# How to back transform from log10 ~ log10 regression in order to predict?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, logarithm, bias-correction

I would like to understand the results of [this paper](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/682070) (they supply all of their R code and raw data [here](https://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.q5j65)). The idea is to regress home range on body mass for a range of taxa.

For one group of birds, they run a regression of `log10.hra ~ log10.mass` and get **2.79702** for their intercept and **1.50145** for log10.mass, the slope.

They then predict home range area at 1kg by creating a variable `log10.mass = c(3)` using the predict function on their model, where 10 is raised to the power, which gives a predicted value of **49421691**.

I would like to see the equation behind this predict function that gives the final value. I've tried to write it out but I must be getting the transformations wrong because I can't arrive at that figure.

Comment: I doubt anything is raised to the power of 10: instead, $10$ must be raised to the power.  This still wouldn't be right for most models, where the back-transformation involves an estimated variance as well (to correct for bias).  Indeed, the formula in the `R` code is `10^(predict(carn.birds.2D.mod, newdata=taxonpredict))`.  What isn't clear about that?

Comment: I haven't looked at the code and bias correction is an issue, as whuber notes. But it might be an error; the estimate seems a bit high given those coefficients.

Comment: I would like to see what the equation is under the hood for predict. If it there were no logarithms involved it would be HR = 2.79702 + 1.50145*mass

Comment: Ignoring bias correction the equation would be `10^(a + (b*3))`, which gives values that are pretty close to those reported in the table for a few other cases that I checked.

Comment: It was that bias correction that was throwing me then. @mkt the only one that is way off is the example I chose.

Comment: You can consider editing your question to focus on the bias correction issue. That may or may not have been addressed elsewhere on the site, so I suggest checking the tag I added first.

Comment: Consider reading the paper by [Newman (1993)](http://139.70.2.61/people/newman_mc/pubs/Newman1993.pdf) about bias in regression with log-transformed data.